# Expose different types of the same function of a templated class

Tags: c++

In case of a templeted class. How can I expose its static function (of all its instances) for everyone to use?

```
  template < typename T >
      class A {
       public:
        void set(T x, T y) {
          a = x;
          b = y;
        }
    
        T a, b;
      };
```

.CPP file: I have some (static) A's (different types):

```
A<int> Ai();
A<char> Ac();
```

.H file :  reason: I want a lot of classes to be able to set them all.

```
A<int>::Ai.set(int x, int y); // how do I do that?
A<char>::Ai.set(char x, char y) ;
```

How can I expose/allow others  to use the set functionality of each of the A's?

I was thinking about wrapping each A with:

```
 void SetAInt(...)
    {
      Ai.Set(...);
    }
```

and exposing:

```
 // .H file:
 void SetAInt(...);
 void SetAChar(..);
```

How can I do it without a wrapper?

Comment: Your `set` function will not work at all, as shown. Even in a non-templated class. C++ does not work like that.

Comment: Where is the definition of the template? Is it visible to users? If it is visible, you don't need `A<int>::Ai.set(int x, int y);` in a header. If it's not visible, you're out of luck. You can't expose only a function in a class.

Comment: You can't use member variables in a static function. And you must put the entire template definition in the header file (or someplace where code that must use it can see it), so there's no need to do anything more to make the functions accessible.

Comment: But you *can* hide the class and expose a `friend` function that's allowed to modify `a` and `b` if an instance has been provided.

Comment: This is looking kinda [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem  that lead you to this unworkable solution?

Comment: Can you first think about how the non-template version would work? Class templates make classes for you (that's why they're called templates). If you can't figure out how you want the classes to look, then trying to use a template to create them is futile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that is probably close to what you are looking for:

```
template < typename T >
class A {
public:
    static void set(T x, T y) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    static T a, b;
};

template<typename T>
T A<T>::a;

template<typename T>
T A<T>::b;


int main() {
    A<int>::set(10, 20);
    std::cout << A<int>::a << '\n';
    std::cout << A<int>::b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This design would never pass a review.  (The code is correct...it's just that the design is broken)